# What algorithm is needed to extract the zip and rename a folder with a search inside that folder for a specific file?

Tags: python, zip

I don't know much about Python. Prompt the correct code algorithm for the following: I am downloading a zip file. I need to extract it to the some_name folder, and then go into this folder and find the file with the .mod extension and pick its name, then rename the some_name folder to the name from .mod and pack it back into the archive. Beaver good to everyone!

Comment: If you have a specific issue while solving this yourself you can ask here with your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this for renaming:

```py
import zipfile
from io import BytesIO
import os

### if you have zip archive in file
z=zipfile.ZipFile('your.zip')
### if you have zip archive in bytes
z=zipfile.ZipFile(BytesIO(your_bytes))
### extract to some_name
z.extractall('some_name')
### iterate through file names
for name in z.filelist:
    if name.endswith('.mod'):
        break
### split extension
bare=os.path.splitext(name)[0]
os.rename('some_name',bare)
```

And this for packing into zip archive

```py
newz=zipfile.ZipFile('new.zip','w')
for q in os.path.listdir(bare):
    newz.write(os.path.join(bare,q))
newz.close()
```

You don't really need to  extract  the zip file, if you want  just  rename your  folder  ,use this:

```py
for name in z.filelist:
    if name.endswith('.mod'):
       break
os.rename('some_name',name)
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your responsiveness! Immensely grateful!

Answer (score 1):

I suggest using the `shutil` module to do some of this. To extract a .zip file: `shutil.unpack_archive("my_file.zip", "extract_to")`. To make a zip archive: `shutil.make_archive("zip_path_and_name", "zip", "/dir/to/pack/into/archive")`.

The `os` module has some features that might help you find and rename files. To rename a file or directory: `os.rename("/old/file/name", "/new/file/name")`

Finding files is a little more difficult. Depending on where the `.mod` file is in your zip archive, you could use `os.listdir("/dir/that/the_file/is/in/")`, which returns a list of the files and directories in the given directory. You could then iterate through this list, checking if the file ends in ".mod". For example:

```
for file in os.listdir("/dirname/"):
    if file.endswith(".mod"):
        do_something()
```

Here is an example. Replace the path names with the ones you are using:

```
import os
import shutil

# Unpack the archive to a directory
shutil.unpack_archive("/archive/to/unpack", "/dir/that/contains/old_dir_name")

# Look in the directory for the .mod file
for file in os.listdir("/dir/that/contains/old_dir_name/"):
    if file.endswith(".mod"):
        file_name = file.replace(".mod", "")

# Rename the directory according to the file name
os.rename("/dir/that/contains/old_dir_name/", "/dir/that/contains/" + file_name)

# Repack the archive
shutil.make_archive("/archive/to/create", "zip", "/dir/that/contains/" + file_name)
```

Comment: @Razilator: You really should try to write the code yourself, and then post your question *with your failed code* if something doesn't work.

Comment: Thank you so much for your responsiveness! Immensely grateful!